# Filter records based on date in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to filer records based on date from `created_at`.

For this I am passing `from_date` and `to_date` from date-picker in Date Format (e.g. `"%y/%m/%d"`).

Please help me with how to write query in the controller to fetch the records between dates.

```
@users = User.where(['created_at = ? and created_at = ?',from_date,to_date])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can we not do something like this: `User.where(created_at >= 1.year.ago)` - if not, that DSL would be ideal (for me, at least)?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the range syntax, looks cleaner:

```
@users = User.where(:created_at => start_date.to_time..end_date.to_time)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@users = User.where("created_at between (?) and (?)", start_date, end_date)
```

or

```
@users = User.where("created_at >= (?) AND created_at <= (?)", start_date, end_date)
```

or in worst case

```
@users = User.where("created_at between (?) and (?)", start_date.to_time, end_date.to_time)
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is this, it will wrap the dates from 00:00:00 hour and 23:59:59

```
@users = User.where(created_at: from_date.beginning_of_day..to_date.end_of_day)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work 100%.

```
starting_date_month = params[:date_from].split("-")[0].to_i
starting_date_year = params[:date_from].split("-")[1].to_i
ending_date_month = params[:date_to].split("-")[0].to_i
ending_date_year = params[:date_to].split("-")[1].to_i

records = self.where("extract(month from created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ? AND extract(year from created_at) between ? AND ? AND status = ? AND v_id = ?", starting_date_month,ending_date_month,starting_date_year,ending_date_year,6,params[:v_id])
```